# JavaScript - accessing google.maps.marker "title" element for onClick alert box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, onclick, google-maps-markers, title

I created a tennis courts map site for our Meetup group. The basic Google Maps JavaScript code was adapted from an unrelated site that no longer exists.

http://www.gooplusplus.com/las-vegas-tennis-courts/test.html

Currently when you hover the mouse over a tennis court **marker**, you can see the **Marker.title** *tooltip text*. I want to replace it with a simple click on a marker to initiate a JavaScript **alert box** to display this title data.

Perhaps the basic HTML code could be similar to:

```
<div id="map" title="map of courts" onclick="confirm(this.(???).title})"></div>
```

Here is a partial listing of the JavaScript include file:

```
function initialize() { 

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(36.123, -115.1435);

var myOptions = { zoom: 11, center: center, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,zoomControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP},mapTypeControlOptions: {mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID], style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU} };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
var point = '';

point = new google.maps.LatLng(36.153192,-115.262353);
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, title: '$4/hour per person - All American Tennis Park, 4 courts, Buffalo Drive and Oakey'});
marker1.setIcon('yellow-dot.png');

point = new google.maps.LatLng(36.215856,-115.25848);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, title: 'Aloha Shores Park, 2 courts, N Buffalo and W Cheyenne'});
marker2.setIcon('faded-dot.png');

point = new google.maps.LatLng(36.169745,-115.196586);
var marker84 = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, title: 'Heinrich YMCA, 2 courts, 4141 Meadows Lane'});
marker84.setIcon('yellow-dot.png');

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You want an alert box?  Or an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)?

Comment: A simple alert box is more than adequate - the map Marker title field already exists. I just need to know how to reference the field in an onClick statement.

Comment: `this.getTitle()`

Comment: Is getTitle() a valid JavaScript function? 

`<div id="map" title="div title" onclick="alert(this.getTitle());"></div>` does nothing. Even if it is a valid function, wouldn't that refer to the DIV title and not the marker title?

Comment: It would be `this.getTitle()` inside a (Google Maps Javascript API v3) marker click listener function (not an HTML onclick function).

Comment: Thanks. I added a click listener function to the first (top yellow) marker `marker1.addListener('click', function() {alert(this.getTitle())});` and it works. I guess that I have to add 80+ click listeners - one for each marker.

Comment: Oops - not top yellow, yellow marker above "Canyon Gate"

Comment: I would tend to use a "createMarker" function does everything needed for one marker, just pass in the coordinates, the title and the icon...

Comment: I will try to find more information about createMarker. So far, I cannot find a list of valid function parameters. I did decide to replace references to title to heading instead. This eliminates redundant hover tooltip display. `marker1.addListener('click',function(){alert(this.heading)});`

Comment: createMarker is not part of the API, write one to take the parameters you want to provide.